# Composer-php with ZendFramework 1 not working

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

Classes managed through composer do not exist at the point I'm trying to instantiate them, which is in the controller.

I have my Zendframework 1.12.8 file/directory structure like this:

```
project
 - application
 - public
    - index.php
 - library
 - vendor
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
```

The contents of my index.php file are:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Composer autoloader */
if (file_exists(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php'))) {
    require_once realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
}

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

The composer autoload.php is included, but seems to be ignored or overwritten by Zend_Application. According to blogs I've seen this is the correct place to include it. Any clues?

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate a class from one of your dependencies or a class within your application? Is there an `"autoload"` section in your composer.json?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Yes @madebydavid I am trying to instantiate a class from a composer managed dependency - there is no "autoload" section in the composer.json file. I get a fatal error - class not found.

Comment: Which class is not found? Note that Composer cannot replace the autoloading process of Zend Framework 1, which used to be a good idea when there was no PSR-0 invented, but today it is more of a burden. You have to configure it correctly, or more correctly said: You have to place your files in the correct directories for ZF1 autoloading to work.

Comment: Sven - the class not found is `Vimeo`. Composer downloaded this class to the vendor directory. I thought using composer meant I no longer have to "put your files in the correct directories for ZF1" - isn't that the point of composer - it loads classes from vendor directory?

Comment: Right. A colleague found the solutions: we need to prefix the namespace that composer has used when we instantiate the composer-managed class. So `new Vimeo\Vimeo($foo, $bar)` works, or putting `use Vimeo\Video` before making an instance `new Vimeo($foo, $bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Right. A colleague found the solutions: we need to prefix the namespace that composer has used when we instantiate the composer-managed class. So `new Vimeo\Vimeo($foo, $bar)` works, or putting `use Vimeo\Video` before making an instance `new Vimeo($foo, $bar)`.